# onbackpressed no suitable method found to override xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am trying to do exercises in xamarin to learn it. The error I am getting is onbackpressed no suitable method found to override. I'm either missing an assembly reference or using statement at top, or I am putting this override in the wrong spot. Can anybody give me a hand? Thanks

```
using System;
using Android.Webkit;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Text;
using Android.Net;
using Java.Interop;

namespace myNamespace
{
    [Activity (Label = "myapp", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar")]   
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        bool formOpen = false;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            var webview = new WebView(this);
            webview.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            webview.Settings.SetGeolocationEnabled(true);
            webview.AddJavascriptInterface (new MyJSInterface (this), "C");
            webview.SetWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient(this));
            webview.SetWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient(this));
            SetContentView(webview);
            webview.LoadUrl ("http://example.com");
        }
        public override void onBackPressed() {
            if (formOpen == false) {
            base.OnBackPressed();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the method signature is `protected override void OnBackPressed()`  Note that Xamarin uses C# naming conventions, so the method starts with a capital "O"

Comment: Hi, thanks for comment. That's what I originally had, straight from the manual, but that throws the same compile error.

Comment: It's a method on Activity, so you should be OK.  Are you using the correct casing of the method name (capital "O")?

Comment: As you can see from my code above, I am not using the correct case, I am using the android case instead of the xamarin case. They should have made the names identical. Can you add that as a final answer?